# find min/max value over consecutive rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
    name  | value
------------------
   alpha  |    90
    beta  |   105
    beta  |    44
    beta  |    56
   gamma  |    22
    beta  |   111
    beta  |    99
```

I want to find min and max value in consecutive rows, with an output that should be like this:

```
    name  |  min |  max
------------------------
   alpha  |   90 |   90
    beta  |   44 |  105
   gamma  |   22 |   22
    beta  |   99 |  111
```

Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: You need to have some way of defining "consecutive rows."  How can you be sure the rows are ordered in the way you describe in the first table?  Is there some other column we can order by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `id` column, which defines `consecutive rows`, then you can

```
 with t  (id,  name  , value ) as (
 values
    (1, 'alpha',90), 
    (2, 'beta',105), 
    (3,'beta',44), 
    (4,'beta',56), 
    (5,'gamma',22), 
    (6,'beta',111), 
    (7,'beta',99)
  )

  select name,   min(value), max(value) from (
    select  id,  name, value, 
    row_number() over(order  by id)   -
    row_number() over(partition by name   order  by id) as grp
    from t
  ) tt
  group by name, grp
  order by min(id)
```

Demo: https://rextester.com/JUDP87693